# Ensure Completeness of HTTP Messages

Tags: sockets, http

I am currently working on an application that is supposed to get a web page and extract information from its content.

As I learned from my research (or as it seems to me at least), there is no ideal way to determine the end of an HTTP message.

Generally, I found two different ways to do so:

1. Set O_NONBLOCK flag for the socket and fetch data with recv() in a while loop. Assume that the message is complete and break if it occurs once that there are no bytes in the stream.
2. Rely on the HTTP Content-Length header and determine the end of the message with it.

Both ways don't seem to be completely safe to me. Solution (1) could possibly break the recv loop before the message was completed. On the other hand, solution (2) requires the Content-Length header to be set correctly.

What's the best way to proceed in this case? Can I always rely on the Content-Length header to be set?

Comment: Use the protocol, Luke. 'O_NONBLOCK' is useless for what you ask for, I don't even know why you suggested it.   You have to fetch data with recv() in a while loop anyway.

Comment: I came across non-blocking sockets somewhere in my research on the internet (http://binarytides.com/receive-full-data-with-recv-socket-function-in-c/). The problem I have got is that recv would block if there is no more data to fetch, so I should know that this will be the case prior to the call. The solution I've found is assuming that the message is complete when recv produces an E_WOULDBLOCK or E_AGAIN (in non-blocking mode). Then the loop breaks and the application can proceed. Actually, I didn't try this. However, I know now that there is a safe and RFC-compliant way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start here:

> Can I always rely on the Content-Length header to be set?

No, you can't. `Content-Length` is an optional header. However, HTTP messages absolutely *must* feature a way to determine their body length if they are to be RFC-compliant (cf [RFC7230, sec. 3.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3)). That being said, get ready to parse on [chunked encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) whenever a content length isn't specified.

As for your original problem: Ensuring the completeness of a message is actually something that should be TCP's job. But as there are such complicated things like message pipelining around, it is best to check for two things in practice:

1. Have all reads from the network buffer been successful?
2. Is the number of the received bytes identical to the predicted message length?

Oh, and as @MartinJames noted, non-blocking probably isn't the best idea here.

Comment: Thank you very much, also for referring to the RFC. I think I am enlightened now.

Comment: Been a pleasure. Oh, and welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thank you, I am pleased. :)

Answer (score 0):

The end of a HTTP response is defined:

1. By the final (empty) chunk in case Transfer-Encoding chunked is used.
2. By reaching the given length if a Content-length header is given and no chunked transfer encoding is used.
3. By the end of the TCP connection if neither chunked transfer encoding is used not Content-length is given.

In the first two cases you have a well defined end so you can verify that the data  were fully received. Only in the last case (end of TCP connection) you don't know if the connection was closed before sending all the data. But usually you get either case 1 or case 2.

Comment: Thank you for this concise answer!

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier, you might want to provide

```
Connection: close
```

header when making HTTP request - than web-server will close connection after giving you the full page requested and you will not have to deal with chunks.

It is only a viable option if you only are interested in this single page, and will not request additional resources (script files, images, etc) - in latter case this will be a very inefficient solution for both your app and the server.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting option! Thank you.